# como hago un procedimiento almacenado error 1136

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

estoy aprendiendo a usar MySQL y estoy intentando hacer un procedimiento almacenado para eliminar registros, pero al momento de ejecutar el call me aparece ´**Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**´.

```
*DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Eliminaremple;
CREATE PROCEDURE Eliminaremple (
 in e_dni INT)
BEGIN
DELETE FROM personas WHERE dni = e_dni;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
CALL Eliminaremple(151520);
```

el DNI que tengo el en call si esta registrado en mi tabla, cuando le quito uno o mas números funciona pero no hace ningún cambio.
[image: esto me sale cuando pongo 151520]
[image: y esto cuando le pongo 15152, pero este no lo tengo registrado]

Comment: Buenas, Alberto, seguramente no esté relacionado pero ¿cómo puedes tener definido un DNI como entero? ¿Qué pasa con la letra del DNI?

Comment: Hola Alberto, 
Para que la gente te pueda asistir mejor con tu duda, podrías añadir el create table de "personas" ??

Comment: @RubioRic Bueno... en realidad la letra del DNI se calcula a partir del número. Normalmente se hace que se introduzca en los formularios simplemente para verificar que el usuario ha introducido el DNI correcto (y válido) puesto que es muy fácil ver si esa letra pertenece a ese número y es muy fácil detectar una errata al escribirlo.

Comment: @Benito-B Eh, sí, ya sé que la letra se calcula y que se usa para verificarlo pero una vez validado, se suele almacenar completo. O al menos no hay una regla universal sobre cómo almacenarlo.

Comment: Suena a algún `TRIGGER` que se estaría disparando en `personas`